# Rails showing the html tag to link_to in email instead my link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

in my body of my email sending through rails I put the following:

**send_email.text.erb**

```
<%= @greeting %>,

Click on this link: <%= link_to 'Accept Items', @url %>,
```

When I receive the email I see the following:

```
Hi,

Click on this link: <a href="http://example.com/bla"> Accept Items </a>
```

How can I display the link instead showing the html tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the name of the file

Instead of a text file `send_email.text.erb` make it html as in `send_email.html.erb`